# App crashes after launch

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

This app am working with works fine with less no of images to be specific less size of images.But i need to use a lot of images,and was unable to install in phone internal memory I tried installing the app on my sd card and got this error .
Can not understand why.
How to resolve this

This is what the log cat says

```
E/dalvikvm-heap(17405): Out of memory on a 3234424-byte allocation.
E/AndroidRuntime(17405): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(17405): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mystictreegames.pagecurl/com.mystictreegames.pagecurl.StandaloneExample}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class com.mystictreegames.pagecurl.PageCurlView
E/AndroidRuntime(17405):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2343)
E/AndroidRuntime(17405):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
E/AndroidRuntime(17405):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
E/AndroidRuntime(17405):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
E/AndroidRuntime(17405):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
E/AndroidRuntime(17405):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
E/AndroidRuntime(17405):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
E/AndroidRuntime(17405):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(17405):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
E/AndroidRuntime(17405):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
E/AndroidRuntime(17405):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
E/AndroidRuntime(17405):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(17405): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class com.mystictreegames.pagecurl.PageCurlView
E/AndroidRuntime(17405):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
```

and my memory card is almost empty.

This is standalone_example.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <com.mystictreegames.pagecurl.PageCurlView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/dcgpagecurlPageCurlView1"
        android:background="@drawable/background">
    </com.mystictreegames.pagecurl.PageCurlView>
</LinearLayout>
```

and my main.xml contains nothing but an imagebutton 
should I post that also ??

Comment: can you post your xml file there is a error in xml file..

Comment: post your xml file , there is problem there

Comment: There is no error in the XML.  The image referenced by it is simply too large.  What size is the image?

Comment: @ simon currently 35 images using almost 10 mb

Comment: is PageCurlView placed in com.mystictreegames.pagecurl ?

Comment: Not the file size, that's not relevant.  What resolution (x,y)?

Comment: @ simon in an average 646X485 
if it is big what should be it ideally ?

Comment: @ Rudi https://github.com/MysticTreeGames/android-page-curl

i just tried adding some more images to the git hub project

it is working fine for less no of images as well .SO I beleive package declaration is ok

Comment: 646x485 is about 2.5MB per image!  (645 x 485 x 4 bytes).  For 35 images, that's about 85MB!!!!  You must either make the images smaller (there is no *ideal* size, only how much RAM is needed to load them) or load them in code using bitmap scaling.  There are plenty of answers on here or just search Google to find how to do this.  You cannot fix this without doing one or both of these things.

Comment: @ Simon thanks.
but the images are not that of great quality only 561 kb

Comment: Once again, the file size is not relevant since the images are compressed on disk.  You are running out of heap memory, nothing to do with how much space you have on your SDCard.  Android cannot load all of those images.  When an image is loaded into RAM, unless you scale it, it take width times height times 4 bytes so on average, your images need 2.5MB of heap space EACH.  No Android device that I know of has heap size anywhere near 85MB.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `PageCurlView`  is placed in `com.mystictreegames.pagecurl`

Answer (score -1):

You must recycle bitmaps using bitmap.recycle(). If you don't recycle your bitmaps you risk an out of memory exception.

so use

```
bitmap.recycle();
bitmap = null;
```

This will assure the bitmap is garbage collected.

Or else if this is memory issue then you can use

```
 android:largeHeap="true"
```

inside your manifest application tag. This will allow you to load more bitmap... Hope this will help you. Happy Coding...

Comment: Since the OP is not loading images in code, this is irrelevant and no amount of large heap will let you load 35 images at that resolution.